# Is the expression "North Star" (meaning a constant or guide) commonly used in the Southern Hemisphere?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions

Since the North Star isn't visible below the Equator, I'm wondering whether English speakers in, for example, Australia or South Africa, would typically use or understand this expression.  If not, is there an equivalent expression involving the Southern Cross or any of its constituent stars?

Comment: Only 10-12% of all humans live in the southern hemisphere, and the English speakers brought their language from, er, Britain.  Figures of speech don;t depend on visible stars. There is an Australian company called Polestar Pilates.

Comment: People I know in the northern hemisphere don't commonly say "north star" (meaning a constant or guide) but "guiding light".

Comment: It's a well-known concept throughout the English-speaking world, and given that most people now don't need stars for guidance (at least in ordinary life), the metaphorical idea of the north star as a kind of guiding light is probably the principle meaning everywhere. Of course, if you DO need to find your directions, the Southern Cross is very useful for finding due south (at least in Australia).

Comment: Not really an answer, but RE: North, in Latin America, which is mostly S.Hem., to "lose one's North" is understood metaphorically as "to lose a sense of direction" or "behave erratically". I speculate that this term Is likely in use wherever sea-faring Europeans have influenced or replaced the native lexicon.

Answer (score 1):

Not a native speaker, but born and raised in South America.

"Guiding star(s)" is an expression that is used often (e.g. "Jane has been my guiding star since I moved here", "I'll follow my guiding stars") and of course, expressions referring to North, since that's where compasses point to, even in the southern hemisphere.

In Portuguese there is even "desnortear" (verb) / "desnorteado" (adjective) which literally means "un-Northed" and translates as "bewilder" / "disorient"

Comment: Isn't "Guiding Star" more likely to be drawn from the New Testament story of the Magi travelling to see the baby Jesus guided by a mystical star that "went before them until it came to a stop over the place where the child lay" than it is to be taken from the North (more commonly Pole) star. The Pole Star is a fixed point of reference in the northern sky rather than a "guiding star" which you follow.